# Where and how can i get account id to be used with chrome.identity.getAuthToken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, inboxsdk

I am building a chrome extension for gmail using InboxSDK and i need to authenticate users with google to use gmail API.

There is built in functionality to authenticate user with google using chrome.identity.getAuthToken, but it uses chrome user to do authentication by default.

Documentation specifies that getAuthToken function can optionally take AccountInfo as an argument and that it will determine whose token should be returned.

AccountInfo has only one property, id, but i am not sure where and how to retrieve that id given i have email of user i want to authenticate.

Here is a [link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) to getAuthToken documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I saw it right, you dont have to enter an account-id. Perhabs it is enough to leave it empty and let chrome decide which account he wants to use. You should give this a try.

Comment: I need the control over who will get authenticated, because i need different logins per different gmail accounts, and default will always use the same account, the one signed in to chrome.

Comment: After a bit of searching I saw that you can use the mail address as account id. Perhabs this can help.